# Can't get my Array to cancel at 0

Tags: java, arrays

I'm trying to get my Array to cancel when a user inputs 0, but it seems to want to cancel at any inputted number.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Assignment2
{
     public static void main (String[] args)
     {

    Scanner scan= new Scanner(System.in);
    int count=0;
    double[] nums= new double[100];

    for(int i=0;i<nums.length;++i)
    {
        nums[i]= scan.nextDouble();
        nums[i]=i;
        if (i == 0){
            break;}
        count++;
        }
}
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're testing `i` (your loop counter), not whatever the user actually input. You probably want:

```
nums[i] = scan.nextDouble();
if (nums[i] == 0) {
   break;
}
```

instead. Plus, your `nums[i] = i` line totally trashes whatever DID get input, and replaces it with the loop counter value, you're basically storing your loop values. That makes the user input totally pointless.

Comment: If this is the correct answer, you need to mark it as such. Give the guy credit.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem lies in your comparison to stop the program. You are using the variable which keeps how many times the loop has run. Since that variable starts at 0, whenever you type **any** value it will always stop the program because you compare it to that counter.

Instead you should compare to what value is stored in the **array**:

```
num[i] == 0
```

This should work as you want:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Assignment2
{
     public static void main (String[] args)
     {

    Scanner scan= new Scanner(System.in);
    int count=0;
    double[] nums= new double[100];

    for(int i=0;i<nums.length;++i){

        nums[i] = scan.nextDouble();  //stores your value

        if (nums[i] == 0){            //checks if the value in the ARRAY is 0
            break;          
        }

        count++;
        }
    }
}
```